# Grails/ Groovy: Formatting Columns using grails.plugin.jxl.builder.ExcelBuilder

Tags: grails, groovy, jxl

I have a working report that results in an Emailed spreadsheet.

I want columns to be sized correctly (or to be close, based on known conditions) and for formats (currency for example) to match requirements. The searches I have done haven't gotten me anywhere, but I am a newbie.

My Controller (simplified):

```
def myReport = {

    def destEmail = 'whositz@domain.com'
    def reportDate
    if(params?.reportDate){
        reportDate = params.reportDate
    } else {
 reportDate = new Date()
    }
    myReportService.execute(reportEmail, reportDate)
}
```

The Service (also simplified):

```
import grails.plugin.jxl.builder.ExcelBuilder
import groovy.sql.Sql
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware

@Mixin(ExcelBuilder)
class myReportService implements ApplicationContextAware {
ApplicationContext applicationContext

def mailService
def dataSource

def execute(String sendToEmail, Date reportDate){
    if(!mailService) {
        mailService = applicationContext.getBean('mailService')
    }
    String path = "/tmp/someReport.xls"
    String reportTitle = reportDate.format('yy.MM')+ ".thisReport"
    def sql = new Sql(dataSource)

    def sqlText = """
        SELECT ys.acct_num AS ACCTNUM, ys.st_name as ACCTNAME, SUM(i.amt_due) AS AMTDUE
        FROM invoice i, yax_sax ys
        WHERE ys.ss_it = true
        AND i.acct_id=ys.id
        AND i.is_on=true
        GROUP BY ys.acct_num, ys.sort_name
        ORDER BY ys.acct_num
    """
    try {
        workbook(path){
            sheet(reportTitle){
                def rowIdx = 0

                cell(0,rowIdx,"Acct #")
                cell(1,rowIdx,"Acct Name")
                cell(2,rowIdx,"Amt Due")
                cell(3,rowIdx,"Trans ID") //Trans Id is a blank field

                rowIdx++
                sql.eachRow(sqlText,[]){ row ->
                    cell(0,rowIdx, row.ACCTNUM)
                    cell(1,rowIdx, row.ACCTNAME)
                    cell(2,rowIdx, row.AMTDUE)
                    cell(3,rowIdx, "")
                    rowIdx++
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Throwable e) {
    e.printStackTrace()
    throw (e)
    } finally {
    sql.close()
    }

    mailService.sendMail {
        multipart true
        to sendToEmail
        subject "An Report for $reportDate"
        body '''
           Report Attached.
       '''
        attachBytes "someReport.xls",'application/pdf', new File(path).readBytes()
    }
}
```

I would appreciate responses on my question as well as ways I can better format questions in  order to get responses.

Answer (score 1):

When using the plugin DSL (workbook, sheet, cell) you are basically calling methods from `grails.plugin.jxl.builder.ExcelBuilder`.
The `ExcelBuilder#cell()` method return a `grails.plugin.jxl.Cell` object which you can use for further manipulation of the cell format and features. The plugins offers some built-in formatting methods which are document [here](https://github.com/sjurgemeyer/grails-jxl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial). However you can apply further formatting by manipulating the underlying JXL object.

For example, you can do the following for having a cell with currency format:

Controller code

```
class ReportController {

    def reportService

    def index() {
        response.setContentType('application/vnd.ms-excel')
        response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="example.xls"')
        reportService.execute(response.outputStream)
    }
}
```

Service code

```
import grails.plugin.jxl.Cell
import grails.plugin.jxl.builder.ExcelBuilder
import jxl.write.NumberFormats
import jxl.write.WritableCellFormat

@Mixin(ExcelBuilder)
class ReportService {

    def execute(OutputStream outputStream){
        String reportTitle = new Date().format('yy.MM')+ ".thisReport"

        try {
            workbook(outputStream){
                sheet(reportTitle){
                    cell(0, 0, "Currency Example")

                    Cell myCell = cell(0,1, 1000)
                    WritableCellFormat currencyFormat = new WritableCellFormat(NumberFormats.ACCOUNTING_FLOAT);
                    myCell.format = currencyFormat
                }
            }
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            throw (e)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to stem from using ExcelBuilder via @Mixin(ExcelBuilder). There is an option on 'cell' for cell(int col, int row, Object value, Map props), but 'props' seems to exclusively refer to fonts. When using the pattern you demonstrated, the formatting does not take and I get a Warning : "Cannot assign object to 'Cell'"

Comment: I updated the answer with the complete controller and service code. I tested this code to be working with Grails 2.1.4 and version 0.54 of the JXL plugin

Answer (score 0):

this works for me, using the mixin, and grails 2.3.5.

```
def setColWidth(def sheet, def col, def width){
    CellView cv = sheet.getColumnView(col);
    cv.setSize(width * 256 + 100); /* Every character is 256 units wide, so scale it. */
    sheet.setColumnView(col, cv);

}

def setColWidths(def sheet){
    setColWidth(sheet, 0, 16)
    setColWidth(sheet, 1, 14)
    setColWidth(sheet, 2, 14)
    setColWidth(sheet, 5, 14)
    setColWidth(sheet, 6, 14)
    setColWidth(sheet, 7, 14)
    setColWidth(sheet, 10, 20)
}
```